# The pandas table is inserting 0 rows in mysql database?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mysql-python

When I try to put data in MySQL database it only puts in the structure data, and there are no rows inserted into the MySQL database. What could be the issue?

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import numpy as np

class Database:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.database = database
        self.connection = None

    def get_db(self):
        try:
            if not self.connection:
                self.connection = create_engine(f'mysql+mysqlconnector://{self.user}:{self.password}@{self.host}/{self.database}')
                print("Connected to the database.")

            return self.connection.connect()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")

db_instance = Database(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='test2')
db_connection = db_instance.get_db()

np.random.seed(0)
number_of_samples = 10
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'feature1': np.random.random(number_of_samples),
    'feature2': np.random.random(number_of_samples),
    'class':    np.random.binomial(2, 0.1, size=number_of_samples),
    },columns=['feature1','feature2','class'])

frame.to_sql('ds_attribution_probabilities', con=db_connection, 
             index=False, if_exists='append')
```

I tried adding **method=None**, adding **dframe** but nothing worked at all.

Comment: Aside: There's no need for `columns=` if they're the same as the dictionary keys.

Comment: even without columns, the data is still not being inserted.

Comment: That's why I said "Aside". It has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: that frame is something i found online just for testing purposes but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t see a commit.

```
 # Add the following line to commit changes
db_connection.commit()

# Close the connection when done
db_connection.close()
```

Comment: Any DB operation has to be committed. There’s an SQLAlchemy property for autocommit. Look at the docs to set it. Also, please,  mark the answer as useful if you consider it, that’s how others can know it.